# Create view based on table in MS VISIO 2003

Tags: microsoft-office, database, microsoft-visio, erd

I'm working on a physical [ERD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model) in [Microsoft Visio 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio), and I want to create some views based on only one table.  Right now I've having to manually add all the columns from parent table.

Is there a way to base the view on the table, or perhaps drag specific columns of it to the view?

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail?  I'm wondering why the standard menu item Database -> Reverese Engineer would not allow you to do this.

Comment: I am designing the table and views in VISIO, it doesn't exist in a database for me to reverse engineer.